# Error - MSB3030 Microsoft.Common.targets(3390,5) switch from .NET 4.0 Profile to Full .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, vb.net, compiler-errors

my Problem Compile error happens if i'm startup the programm. 
I've switched from .NET 4.0 Profile to .NET 4.0 Full now i'm getting strange errors. 
I had to switch to Full 4.0 for using HttpUtility.UrlEncode().

This lines of code make the compile process stopping

```
MessageBox.Show(Application.StartupPath)
If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(Application.StartupPath) = True Then
    MessageBox.Show("ok")
End If
```

The error i receive is. The Problem is Checking Directory Exists..

"Microsoft.Common.targets(3390,5): error MSB3030: Datei "obj\x86\Debug\ShopsteImporter.exe" could not copy"

if i remove the lines of source it compiles normal.

What also not is working is.

```
client.DownloadFile(ListView1.Items(icount).SubItems(3).Text, "C:\importierte Bilder\" & strFileName(strFileName.Length - 1))
```

Thanks for any Help, i can't find any answer/solution in the internet for this problem.

I understand the problem under Add-Reference i can't see system.io to import it. 
But there is no Error in the top of the programm Imports System.IO.

Update: 
if i use x64 the programm works normal if i switch to any cpu not, x32 also not.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me those errors are related. Sure you closed that last debugging session? Is the file still open? Any other errors?

Comment: It's when i startup the programm in the IDE

Answer (score 0):

i've installed Visual Studio 2013 the bug is gone.

it was really confusing i found no other way to fix it.